# use an iCloud+ «hide my email» apple ID forward address as an alias to send mail

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, apple-id

**Hide my email** is the neat feature introduced by apple earlier, and since then I have been trying to figure out how I can use those forward addresses as sender address when composing emails on the iPhone.

The adressess don’t appear when tapping on current sender address when composing an email in apple mail.

I figured I should try to add one of the «hide my email» forward addresses manually in `appleid.apple.com` as an alias, but the process of adding an alias stop at waiting for a verification code from the appleid service.

The use of «hide my email» if I can’t send or reply an email is limited to signing up for newsletters.

Any insight on this?

edit: also in the browser `icloud.com/Mail` behind the gear icon you can add up to 3 aliases, but the rule «Alias names may only contain unaccented letters, numbers, periods, and underscores.» disqualify the generated «hide my email» addresses as they typically contain a `-` sign

2nd edit: I did some further digging and found a related feature in a recent team up between 1password and fastmail called "masked email" and integration. Fastmail supposedly provide the ability to send from the randomly generated addresses.

3rd edit: an extra feature with icloud+ is custom domain as icloud email. you will need to update DNS records at your domain registrar/host with `TXT, SPF, MX servers, and DKIM` to point to icloud. This feature do allow for use of more addresses pointing to the same mailbox, and new addresses are fairly simple to create and delete, but they will not be random like those "hide my email" generate as you will have to manage them yourself, and they all point to your own custom domain anyway

4th edit: don’t know why I didn’t notice this feature before, but apparently «Hide my email» feature seamless reply to email, only not a send from option when composing email.

<strike>also the custom domain feature with icloud+ appear to have an issue with DKIM signing email sent from an iphone mail app. For some reason sending from the browser version of icloud mail sign sent mail with DKIM.</strike>

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is no way to send an email like that as spammers would _love_ that feature.

Comment: why would spammers love this feature? they already have the ability to use aliases

Comment: Because the mails would come from the reputable `icloud.com` domain, which most companies probably don't want to block/blacklist.

Comment: what is stopping spammers from already yesterday using icloud.com

Comment: Missing/incorrect SPF and DKIM.

Comment: do you care to elaborate on how SPF and DKIM becomes an issue with aliases?

Comment: This is becoming a chat, so it's my last comment on the topic. SPF and DKIM are used to validate whether an email originated from an authorized source (servers). Spammers cannot fake that and get flagged if they send from a non-Apple server but claim to send from `something@icloud.com`. If a spammer would be able to send via Apple's servers instead, most systems would trust the mail as it came from a legitimate source of `icloud.com`, making it hard to detect as spam and hard for admins to filter without hurting legitimate users (managers/customers sending from their iCloud account).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t appear to be the design intent of the service. Apple is setting up inbound only aliases so that multiple mailboxes funnel mails to one account, not setting up multiple accounts or aliases to send out mail.

Apple iCloud isn’t currently the service for masking outgoing mails or handling multiple accounts, so you can’t configure your way around this limitation by client side configuration changes.

Check out https://www.fastmail.com/ -  I’ve used them in tandem with Apple mail for almost a decade and couldn’t be happier with the value both provide me. Each vendor does things I like, with Fastmail being more customizable and having some extra features Apple doesn’t offer.

Comment: multiple accounts where never a question. with aliases you already have the ability to send and receive in the same mailbox with different addresses, only limited to 3, or as the new icloud+ feature custom domains allow for even more custom addresses in the same mailbox

Comment: Thanks - my wording wasn't clear or complete - does my edit make more sense @vardaasen ? The short answer is no, Apple didn’t design this to let you send mail from a private address.

Answer (score 0):

When I’m composing an email from my iPhone, using the default Mail app, I CAN select the From: field and choose “Hide my email” at which point Apple will create a NEW masked/alias address to send that particular email from!

So indeed Apple IS providing this service, only you can’t select an [Apple created] hidden email created previously to sign up with a service/site you intend to use going forward!

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so I removed the part of your answer which seemed to reply to other answers/comments already posted.